# how to skip well-formedness check XML

Tags: java, html, xml, xpath

I am using Xpath (and java) to extract information from some websites. However my problem is that since some of these websites are not well-formed, I cannot process them. Is there any way to avoid well-formedness check or alternatively specify tags that should'nt be checked for well-formedness?

Thanks
Rp

Answer (score 5):

Preprocess with [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/ for turning the HTML into a DOM object

Answer (score 2):

[TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) is a SAX-compliant parser written in Java that can handle all kind of broken HTML. Try to use TagSoup as your XML parser and then process the output through Xpath.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use an XML parser to parse HTML.  You'd be better off using a library such as [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) or [HtmlParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/).